# Adding boost to terms in a Filter at query time

Tags: java, solr, lucene, filtering

I am working on a SynonymFilter for Lucene/Solr that is only run at query time to expand the query using a thesaurus. The problem I am running into is that the synonyms that I add into the query have the same "weight" or "boost" as the original terms, so I can end up getting a lot of noise in the results.

Is there a way to set the "weight" or "boost" of a single term from within a Filter?

If not, how else could I do it?

(Similar to http://search-lucene.com/jd/lucene/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html, but with less weight on the synonym terms.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the weight of a single term from within a filter or as part of a query. Using the [eDisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) parser you could do something like the following:

`&defType=edismax&q=<your query terms>&qf=title:superman^2`

This would boost all occurrences of superman in the title field. If I understood what you were asking this should do what you need. If you have a large number of these, you could specify the`qf` boosts in the [defaults settings for your requestHandler](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig).